# Can't user Composer to install own git repository

Tags: git, github, composer-php

I'm trying to include a repository I created on github, using Composer.
In my composer.json i have:

```
"repositories": [
    ...
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/unknownfrequency/zendservice_discogs"
    }
], 

"require": {
    "unknownfrequency/zendservice_discogs": "dev-master",
}
```

When i run 
$>composer install -vvv i get:

```
@unknown-2~/workspace/imusic $  composer install -vvv
Downloading composer.json
Loading composer repositories with package information
...
Downloading ..//packages.zendframework/packages.json
Downloading ...api.github/repos/unknownfrequency/zendservice_discogs
Downloading         ...github/repos/unknownfrequency/zendservice_discogs/contents/composer.json?ref=master
Downloading ../api.github/repos/unknownfrequency/zendservice_discogs/commits/master
Downloading ...//api.github/repos/unknownfrequency/zendservice_discogs/tags
Downloading ...//api.github/repos/unknownfrequency/zendservice_discogs/git/refs/heads
Reading composer.json of zendframework/zendservice-discogs (master)
Importing branch master (dev-master)
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Downloading https://packagist.org/p/provider-            latest$cf8f23c1297b4c86275ae395aed6402ba4f5cc186e587b80f8dd5ecca7d60e3f.json
Installing dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package unknownfrequency/zendservice_discogs could not be found in     any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-    stability setting
```

I've tried to fix this for so many hours now. Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually just a matter of doing a:

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

Answer (score 1):

> The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-    stability setting"

That's the problem. You require a development branch, but you do not allow to include development stability in general.

Add `"minimum-stability":"dev"` to your composer.json file.